# Write data from object to file

Tags: c#, object

let's say I have a class

```
class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Data(string name, string lastname, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        LastName = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

I want to get the age of a person, if it's <18 then print all the data to Kids.csv, else I want it to be printed to Adults.csv

I know it's simple and I managed to do that, but the teacher said that my code didn't look like objective programming. He told me that I need to use method to return array and create other method for writing the array to file or something.

Comment: i think, better place for your question is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's better to post your question at codereview hub. Don't forget to include actual code you've written.

Comment: Please clarify what kind of help you are looking from SO. You know exactly what is expected of your code - so maybe you don't know what array is or how to return one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at this for something basic to model your approach on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Data
{
    public class DataList
    {
        public List<Data> lData { get; set; }
        public bool WriteToCSV(string strPath)
        {
            bool ret = false;

            try
            {
                List<Data> lKids = this.lData.Where(x => x.Age < 18).ToList();
                List<Data> lAdults = this.lData.Where(x => x.Age >= 18).ToList();
                if (lKids.Count > 0)
                {
                    string strFilePath = strPath + "Kids.csv";
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath))
                    {
                        foreach (Data p in lKids)
                        {
                            string strRow = (char)34 + p.Name + (char)34 + "," + (char)34 + p.LastName + (char)34 + "," + p.Age.ToString();
                            sw.WriteLine(strRow);
                        }
                    }
                    ret = true;
                }
                if (lAdults.Count > 0)
                {
                    string strFilePath = strPath + "Adults.csv";
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath))
                    {
                        foreach (Data p in lAdults)
                        {
                            string strRow = (char)34 + p.Name + (char)34 + "," + (char)34 + p.LastName + (char)34 + "," + p.Age.ToString();
                            sw.WriteLine(strRow);
                        }
                    }
                    ret = true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Data(string name, string lastname, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            LastName = name;
            Age = age;
        }
    }
}
```